# Connect hsm classic and new hsm from same EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hsm

Can we connect hsm classic and new hsm from same EC2 instance if present in the same VPC. Are there any giudelines regarding managing both hsm from same ec2 instance.